# Can we make Spring JPA Specifications work with EntityGraph?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entitygraph

I am implementing a dynamic query logic using JPA specifications on an entity. The entity is having multiple relations with other entities. I am running into the issue of generating too many queries while executing JPA specifications.

Is there a way to combine JPA specifications `findAll(specification, page)` with EntityGraph so that we can one query generated while executing the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is absolutely possible to pass `EntityGraph` using `EntityGraphJpaSpecificationExecutor`

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository
        extends JpaRepository<EntityClassName, DatatypeOfPrimaryKey>, EntityGraphJpaSpecificationExecutor<EntityClassName> {
}

userRepository.findAll(specification, pageable, new NamedEntityGraph(EntityGraphType.FETCH, "graphName"))
```

Comment: trying to use the cosium lib and doing the above, i get... Error creating bean with name 'UserRepository': invocation of init method failed; nested exception is IllegalArgumentException: failed to create query for method public abstract Optional EntityGraphJpaSpecificationExecutor.findOne(Specification, EntityGraph)! No property findOne found for type EntityClassName!